# How to set a default theme option after installing theme?

Tags: theme-options, options

I'm using a class to add a theme option page to my theme.

I need to set some default values upon theme activation or installation, since some of these values are strings, and if i try to get the option using `get_option`, i won't know if the the user actually left them blank or it's not set at all.

```
<?php 
    class Theme_Options {
        public function __construct() {
            // We only need to register the admin panel on the back-end
            if ( is_admin() ) {
                add_action( 'admin_menu', array( 'Theme_Options', 'add_admin_menu' ) );
                add_action( 'admin_init', array( 'Theme_Options', 'register_settings' ) );
            }
        }
        // Returns all theme options 
        public static function get_theme_options() {
            return get_option( 'theme_options' );
        }
        // Returns single theme option
        public static function get_theme_option_value( $id ) {
            $options = self::get_theme_options();
            if ( isset( $options[$id] ) ) {
                return $options[$id];
            }
        }
        // Add sub menu page
        public static function add_admin_menu() {
            add_menu_page(
                esc_html__( 'Theme\'s Options', 'sample' ),
                esc_html__( 'Theme\'s Options', 'sample' ),
                'manage_options',
                'theme-settings',
                array( 'Theme_Options', 'create_admin_page' )
            );
        }
        // Register a setting and its sanitization callback.
        public static function register_settings() {
            register_setting( 'theme_options', 'theme_options', array( 'Theme_Options', 'sanitize' ) );
        }
        // Sanitization callback
        public static function sanitize( $options ) {
            // If we have options lets sanitize them
            if ( $options ) {
                // Input
                if ( ! empty( $options['sample_input'] ) ) {
                    $options['sample_input'] = sanitize_text_field( $options['sample_input'] );
                } else {
                    unset( $options['sample_input'] ); // Remove from options if empty
                }
            }
            // Return sanitized options
            return $options;
        }
        // Settings page output
        public static function create_admin_page() { ?>
            <div class="wrap">
                <form method="post" action="options.php">
                    <?php settings_fields( 'theme_options' ); ?>
                    <table class="form-table"><tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="row">
                                <?php esc_html_e( 'Sample input', 'sample' ); ?>
                            </th>
                            <td>
                                <?php $value = self::get_theme_option_value( 'sample_input' ); ?>
                                <input type="text" name="theme_options[sample_input]" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $value ); ?>"> 
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody></table>
                    <?php submit_button(); ?>
                </form>
            </div>
        <?php }
    }
new Theme_Options();
// Helper function to use in theme to return a theme option value
function get_theme_option( $id = '' ) {
    return Theme_Options::get_theme_option_value( $id );
}?>
```

**Note:** I removed a lot of unnecessary lines to avoid the question being too long

Since the class is storing serialized data, i thought it's not the best idea to just save a default string to the database.

Is there any way to run this class upon activation and store some default values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using a hook to store the defaults, you can write the logic straight into `get_theme_options` - if the value is `false`, there are no options saved yet:

```
public static function get_theme_options() {
    $options = get_option( 'theme_options' );

    if ( $options === false ) {
        $options = [
            'key' => 'default_value',
        ];

        add_option( 'theme_options', $options );
    }

    return $options;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i usually forget the most obvious approaches :) BTW sorry for the delay.